# Get hiera value in puppet manifest with nested keys

Tags: yaml, puppet, hiera

I'm new to using hiera with puppet (and somewhat new to puppet).

I've written this bit of yaml:

```
---
web_mysql_server:
 mysql_database: "my_production"
```

and then I try to use it in a puppet manifest thus:

```
database => hiera('web_mysql_server::mysql_database'),
```

And this does not work, generating the error

```
Error: Could not find data item web_mysql_server::mysql_database
  in any Hiera data file and no default supplied at
  /vagrant/puppet/modules/web_mysql_server/manifests/init.pp:33
  on node railstest.vm
```

(where I've added some `'\n'`'s for readability here).

I suspect (hope!) this is a simple syntax error that I'm not getting.  Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what version of puppet are you using?

Comment: Puppet is 3.4.3 (ubuntu 14.04 LTS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based in [hiera documentation](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/latest/puppet.html?_ga=1.87127640.1337788561.1460043121#interacting-with-structured-data-from-hiera), the proper syntax for accessing nested keys is

```
hiera('web_mysql_server.mysql_database')
```

This syntax for qualified keys has not been around always, the documentation says it's from Hiera 2.0.

I know we use puppet 3.8.3 and qualified keys are not supported yet in our setup. We work around this limitation with this approach:

```
$mysql_configuration = hiera('web_mysql_server')
# ...
database => $mysql_configuration['mysql_database']
```

Comment: dpkg says I'm using hiera 1.3, and the dot notation also doesn't work for me.  Pre-hiera 2.0, then, nested keys weren't even possible?

Comment: I believe so. I will update my answer with a possible solution